# How to have a good project code organization in Xcode?

Tags: swift, xcode, code-organization

My project i becoming messy because of the number of files, i need advices from devs.
For exemple i have string extensions, at start i was creating one per target. One for ios, one for watch OS etc ...

so I had something like :

- extensionString.swift for iOS
- extensionStrinWatchg.swift for watchOS
- extensionStringTE.swift for today Extension

But with that method i got common code part between some targets and repeating code is never good, you agree.

So i started to make commun String extension files like

- extensionStringIOS+watch.swift
- extensionStringIOS+TD+watch.swift
- extensionStringIOS+TD.swift
  etc ...

adding to this the version that are only for a specific target we get :

- extensionString.swift for ios
- extensionStrinWatch.swift for watchOS
- extensionStringTE.swift for today Extension
- extensionStringIOS+watch.swift
- extensionStringIOS+TD+watch.swift
- extensionStringIOS+TD.swift
  etc ...

You understand ... Thats a lot and that's messy. I loose time to find in which file to go
So now imagine this method for everything ...
The number of file become huge ...
I have that problem for extension, classes and others ...

So one file per target -> repeating code
second method : huge number of files, messy project and time wasting

So i have an idea but i'd like to know if it's the right way to do. What's the convention ?

My idea is to have one single extensionString.swift shared between all targets in my project and use things like this for code parts that shouldn't be used for all targets

```swift
#if !os(watchOS)
// do something
#else
// do something different
#if
```

So this applied in my project (not only extensions but class etc ..) could make me delete tons of files and regroup like this function for exemple :

```swift
/// boolean indicating if the user enabled the weekend days setting
    static var isWeekendDaysSettingEnabled: Bool {
        #if !os(watchOS)
            if IS_ICLOUD_ENABLED {
                return NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore.default.bool(forKey: KeyValueID.weekendDays.rawValue)
            } else {
                return UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: KeyValueID.weekendDays.rawValue)
            }
        #else
            return UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "weekendDays")
        #endif
    }
```

Comment: At least a good *code organization* is to use `bool(forKey`

Comment: @vadian just changed it, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I think every answer here should start with big fat IMHO

There's no silver bullet and you have to decide which way to choose depending on your particular project.

As for me, I would try to separate all the logic into small frameworks, eg ExtensionsCrossplatform, ExtensionsIOS, ExtensionsWatchOS, etc.

An idea of having everything in one place is not so good and will lead to tight coupling between all the modules and platforms.

In fact, many big apps are comprised of big amount of tiny modules (more than 50).

Here's a video, which can describe the idea more https://badootech.badoo.com/the-immense-benefits-of-not-thinking-in-screens-6c311e3344a0